# Custom List Button - Merge Field not evaluating (is blank) in URL

Tags: custom-button, merge-field

I'm trying to initiate a flow from a list button that sits on a dynamic Related List on the Taskray__Project__c object, with a standard retURL parameter and another passed in parameter to the flow. I'm 100% certain the url works if I hardcode the Account ID in to test it, but when I use a merge field, it keeps evaluating that field to blank/null.

The "Parent_Account_Field__c" is a Lookup(Account) field. When I start the flow, it evaluates to null. When I finish the flow, it gives me a redirect error, because it's still null.

```
/flow/Flow_POC?ParentAccountId={!TASKRAY__Project__c.Parent_Account_Field__c}&retURL=/lightning/r/Account/{!TASKRAY__Project__c.Parent_Account_Field__c}/related/TASKRAY__trProjectAccount__r/view
```

Any thoughts on why it wouldn't be working?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it can't find the Taskray__Project__c to evaluate?

Answer (score 1):

Taskray__Project__c is the related list? If so, you need to remove the "TASKRAY__Project__c." on the merge tags and add ".id".

{!TASKRAY__Project__c.Parent_Account_Field__c} --> {!Parent_Account_Field__c.id}

Comment: Thanks! I think I ended up going a different route altogether, but this does sound like it would work! I would mark it as best answer, but I don't have the original code to test this with anymore.